# Match two strings in Selenium web-driver with behavior driven development in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bdd, gherkin

I am writing a test in which products qty should match to filter qty, but when I run code, I get this error:

```
'WebElement' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Here I am sharing my BDD code

```
@then('product count should match filter count')
def step_impl(context):
    product_count = WebDriverWait(context.browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="narrow-by-list"]/dd[7]/ol/li[8]/a'))
    )
    print(product_count.text)
    filter_count = context.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="amount"]').text
    if(filter_count[8:-1] == product_count[6:-7]):
        print('product count matches with filter count')
    else:
        print('count not matches')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem by this on in Behavior Driven Development.

```
filter_count = WebDriverWait(context.browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//dl[@id="narrow-by-list"]/dd[7]/ol/li[8]'))
)
print(filter_count.text)
product_count = context.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="amount"]')
print(product_count.text)

if(filter_count.text[8:-1] == product_count.text[6:-8]):
    assert True
else:
    assert False
```